# How to use same MySQL database with both Django and Express.js together?

Tags: mysql, node.js, django, database, express

For Django, ORM makes it very easy to manage tables so I am using Django to manage the outline of the database. How to use express.js to use the same database so that IDEs can suggest field names and queries? Ideally the goal is to avoid or minimize typing manual sql queries in express.js.

Answer (score 0):

You could use API, between Django and Express, but it doesn't make sense to use both of them because both are backend frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of Django is managing tables, use [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) with express.js instead.

Also, most IDE can't suggest field name and queries between different runtimes, say python and node.js, unless there is an extension hack built around it.